# Deserialize primitive long field while using TypeResolverBuilder of Jackson

Tags: java, json, serialization, jackson

When running the following test app

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonTypeInfo;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonFactory;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializationFeature;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.jsontype.impl.StdTypeResolverBuilder;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        // Create test data
        Data data = new Data();
        data.key = 1;
        Map<String, Object> mapData = new HashMap<>();
        mapData.put("longInMap", 2L);
        mapData.put("longAsField", data);

        // Configure Jackson to preserve types
        JsonFactory factory = new JsonFactory();
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper(factory);
        StdTypeResolverBuilder resolver = new StdTypeResolverBuilder();
        resolver.init(JsonTypeInfo.Id.CLASS, null);
        resolver.inclusion(JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY);
        resolver.typeProperty("__t");
        mapper.setDefaultTyping(resolver);
        mapper.enable(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT);

        // Serialize
        String json = mapper.writeValueAsString(mapData);
        System.out.println("json = " + json);

        // Deserialize
        Map deserializedData = mapper.readValue(json, Map.class);
    }

    static class Data {

        public long key;
    }
}
```

I get this output and exception

```
json = {
  "__t" : "java.util.HashMap",
  "longInMap" : [ "java.lang.Long", 2 ],
  "longAsField" : {
    "__t" : "com.pinkmatter.bean.serialization.Main$Data",
    "key" : [ "java.lang.Long", 1 ]
  }
}
Exception in thread "main" com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Class java.lang.Long not subtype of [simple type, class long] (through reference chain: java.util.HashMap["longAsField"]->com.pinkmatter.bean.serialization.Data["key"])
  at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException.wrapWithPath(JsonMappingException.java:379)
  at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException.wrapWithPath(JsonMappingException.java:339)
  at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializerBase.wrapAndThrow(BeanDeserializerBase.java:1591)
  at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.vanillaDeserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:278)
  ...
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Class java.lang.Long not subtype of [simple type, class long]
  at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.type.TypeFactory.constructSpecializedType(TypeFactory.java:359)
  at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.jsontype.impl.ClassNameIdResolver._typeFromId(ClassNameIdResolver.java:72)
  at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.jsontype.impl.ClassNameIdResolver.typeFromId(ClassNameIdResolver.java:42)
  ...
```

I am trying to serialize a bunch of basic plain old java objects from libraries we are using (so we cannot modify the classes or add annotations), while also trying to preserve the types of values in collections ("longInMap" in the above example must stay a Long object).

The problem is that Jackson throws the above exception when trying to deserialize the primitive `public long key` in the `Data` class. If I change the type to `public int key` then no exception is thrown and deserialization works.

Also, since there are many different types of objects and I don't know at compile time exactly what will be serialized I don't think using mix-ins will work.

Please advise about what I might be doing wrong or of a possible workaround for getting primitive long fields deserialized while also maintaining the types of objects in collections.

I am using Jackson 2.8.3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A workaround was provided here https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/issues/1395

The workaround is to replace

```
StdTypeResolverBuilder resolver = new StdTypeResolverBuilder();
```

with

```
StdTypeResolverBuilder resolver = new StdTypeResolverBuilder() {
        @Override
        public TypeSerializer buildTypeSerializer(SerializationConfig config, JavaType baseType, Collection<NamedType> subtypes) {
            if (baseType.isPrimitive()) {
                return null;
            }
            return super.buildTypeSerializer(config, baseType, subtypes);
        }

        @Override
        public TypeDeserializer buildTypeDeserializer(DeserializationConfig config, JavaType baseType, Collection<NamedType> subtypes) {
            if (baseType.isPrimitive()) {
                return null;
            }
            return super.buildTypeDeserializer(config, baseType, subtypes);
        }

    };
```

A fix was implemented and will be available in jackson-databind 2.8.4 after which the workaround will no longer be required.